# Pandas creates new columns with append

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am trying to compile multiple text files into a single data frame. However, when I join the data frames with Pandas Concat function, the shape of the resulting data frame adds new columns. In the code sample below, data frame 3 has 12 columns rather than 8. Why?

```
**Input:**
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('2011-12-01-data.txt',sep = None, engine = 'python')
df2 = pd.read_csv('2011-12-02-data.txt',sep = None, engine = 'python')
df3= pd.concat([df1, df2])

print(df1.shape)
print(df2.shape)
print(df3.shape)

**Output:** 
df1 shape = (26986, 8)
df1 shape =(27266, 8)
df3 shape =(54252, 12)
```

The I am working with flight data available at http://lunadong.com/datasets/clean_flight.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `header=None` parameter for default columns names `0-7`, because files has no headers. Also if there is separator `tab`, is possible specify it.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('2011-12-01-data.txt',sep = '\t', engine = 'python', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('2011-12-02-data.txt',sep = '\t', engine = 'python', header=None)
df3= pd.concat([df1, df2])

print(df1.shape)
print(df2.shape)
print(df3.shape)
(26987, 8)
(27267, 8)
(54254, 8)

print(df1.columns)
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype='int64')
print(df2.columns)
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype='int64')
print(df3.columns)
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype='int64')
```

Another solution is specify `names` parameter for new column names:

```
names= ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8']
df1 = pd.read_csv('2011-12-01-data.txt',sep = '\t', engine = 'python', names=names)
df2 = pd.read_csv('2011-12-02-data.txt',sep = '\t', engine = 'python', names=names)
df3= pd.concat([df1, df2])

print(df1.shape)
print(df2.shape)
print(df3.shape)
(26987, 8)
(27267, 8)
(54254, 8)

print(df1.columns)
print(df2.columns)
print(df3.columns)
Index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8'], dtype='object')
Index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8'], dtype='object')
Index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8'], dtype='object')
```

---

You get only 12 columns, because some values in first row of both dataframes are same, so from them was created columns names. After `concat` columns are aligned only for this columns. If values was different, there was no align and you get `NaN`s.

```
print(df1.columns)
Index(['aa', 'AA-1007-TPA-MIA', '12/01/2011 01:55 PM', '12/01/2011 02:07 PM',
       'F78', '12/01/2011 03:00 PM', '12/01/2011 02:57 PM', 'D5'],
      dtype='object')

print(df2.columns)
Index(['aa', 'AA-1007-TPA-MIA', '12/02/2011 01:55 PM', '12/02/2011 02:13 PM',
       'F78', '12/02/2011 03:00 PM', '12/02/2011 03:05 PM', 'D5'],
      dtype='object')

print(df3.columns)
Index(['12/01/2011 01:55 PM', '12/01/2011 02:07 PM', '12/01/2011 02:57 PM',
       '12/01/2011 03:00 PM', '12/02/2011 01:55 PM', '12/02/2011 02:13 PM',
       '12/02/2011 03:00 PM', '12/02/2011 03:05 PM', 'AA-1007-TPA-MIA', 'D5',
       'F78', 'aa'],
      dtype='object')
```

---

```
print(df3.head())
  12/01/2011 01:55 PM       12/01/2011 02:07 PM       12/01/2011 02:57 PM  \
0                 NaN      12/1/2011 2:07PM EST      12/1/2011 2:51PM EST   
1                 NaN  12/1/11 2:06 PM (-05:00)  12/1/11 2:51 PM (-05:00)   
2                 NaN  12/1/11 2:06 PM (-05:00)  12/1/11 2:51 PM (-05:00)   
3                 NaN  12/1/11 2:06 PM (-05:00)  12/1/11 2:51 PM (-05:00)   
4                 NaN  12/1/11 2:06 PM (-05:00)  12/1/11 2:51 PM (-05:00)   

  12/01/2011 03:00 PM 12/02/2011 01:55 PM 12/02/2011 02:13 PM  \
0                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN   
1                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN   
2                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN   
3                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN   
4                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN   

  12/02/2011 03:00 PM 12/02/2011 03:05 PM  AA-1007-TPA-MIA   D5  F78  \
0                 NaN                 NaN  AA-1007-TPA-MIA  NaN  NaN   
1                 NaN                 NaN  AA-1007-TPA-MIA  NaN  NaN   
2                 NaN                 NaN  AA-1007-TPA-MIA  NaN  NaN   
3                 NaN                 NaN  AA-1007-TPA-MIA  NaN  NaN   
4                 NaN                 NaN  AA-1007-TPA-MIA  NaN  NaN   

                aa  
0   flightexplorer  
1  airtravelcenter  
2       myrateplan  
3      helloflight  
4        flytecomm
```

---

```
print(df3.tail())
      12/01/2011 01:55 PM 12/01/2011 02:07 PM 12/01/2011 02:57 PM  \
27261                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN   
27262                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN   
27263                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN   
27264                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN   
27265                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN   

      12/01/2011 03:00 PM     12/02/2011 01:55 PM     12/02/2011 02:13 PM  \
27261                 NaN        Dec 02 - 10:20pm        Dec 02 - 10:23pm   
27262                 NaN             10:20pDec 2             10:23pDec 2   
27263                 NaN     2011-12-02 10:20 PM                     NaN   
27264                 NaN     2011-12-02 10:20 pm                     NaN   
27265                 NaN  2011-12-02 10:20PM CST  2011-12-02 10:31PM CST   

          12/02/2011 03:00 PM     12/02/2011 03:05 PM  AA-1007-TPA-MIA    D5  \
27261        Dec 02 - 11:59pm       Dec 02 - 11:51pm*  AA-2059-DFW-SLC    A3   
27262             11:43pDec 2                     NaN  AA-2059-DFW-SLC    A3   
27263     2011-12-02 11:59 PM                     NaN  AA-2059-DFW-SLC   NaN   
27264                     NaN                     NaN  AA-2059-DFW-SLC   NaN   
27265  2011-12-02 11:35PM MST  2011-12-02 11:43PM MST  AA-2059-DFW-SLC   A3    

         F78           aa  
27261  C20/C  travelocity  
27262    C20       orbitz  
27263    NaN      weather  
27264    C20          dfw  
27265   C20    flightwise
```

Answer (score 1):

User jezrael's answer solves the problem. But let me try to explain why pandas added new columns to your concatenated data frame and what went wrong.

#### pandas misread header

When you set header = None, pandas reads the first line of your file as a header and sets it by default to names of each column. Based on your code, these are the two sets of columns one would get for each of your dataframes if header = None.

df1:
['aa',
 'AA-1007-TPA-MIA',
 '12/01/2011 01:55 PM',
 '12/01/2011 02:07 PM',
 'F78',
 '12/01/2011 03:00 PM',
 '12/01/2011 02:57 PM',
 'D5']

df2:
['aa',
 'AA-1007-TPA-MIA',
 '12/02/2011 01:55 PM',
 '12/02/2011 02:13 PM',
 'F78',
 '12/02/2011 03:00 PM',
 '12/02/2011 03:05 PM',
 'D5']

#### Non-Unique columns appended

Finally, when you concatenated the two dataframes, all columns that were not common to df1 and df2 were appended as separate columns. 'aa','AA-1007-TPA-MIA', 'F78' and 'D5' were unique to df1 and df2 while everything else was appended to the list of columns.

This lead to 4(df1&df2) + 4(df1) + 4(df2) = 12 columns